# Does QED have asymptotic freedom?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, physical-constants

QCD has [asymptotic freedom](http://web.mit.edu/physics/people/faculty/docs/wilczek_nobel_lecture.pdf) since the gauge coupling gets smaller with an increasing energy/length/momentum scale. The fine structure constant of QED however has a [Landau Pole](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.01721.pdf). Is it possible to unite the two Gauge coupling constants in a single equation and eliminate the Landau Pole by transfering the asymptotic freedom from QCD to the electroweak interactions or just the U(1) QED such as in the image bellow?
[image: the beta-expansion method]
[the beta-expansion method](https://www.academia.edu/33753427/Improving_the_Accuracy_of_Predictions_for_Running_of_the_Strong_Gauge_Coupling_Constant_and_Removing_the_Landau_Pole_for_the_Fine_Structure_Constant)

Comment: have a look http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.621.8573&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: @annav that's a very interesting article. Thank you for posting it :)